# How to make a JSFiddle anonymous without logging out?

Tags: sharing, jsfiddle

When I'm logged into my JSFiddle account, every fiddle I create has my username in the link, and I can later delete it and make the link useless. If I want to share my fiddle, in Stack Overflow for instance, the fiddle should be anonymous, so it can never be deleted.

Is there any way to make an anonymous fiddle without logging out?

<sub>I'd like something like "create anonymous copy from this fiddle".</sub>

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this without logging out, but you can open an incognito window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> for Chrome, or your browser's menu bar → New incognito window) and go to jsfiddle.net and paste in your code to make an anonymous copy quickly.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+N is specific to Chrome, no? I'm pretty sure the shortcut for Firefox private browsing mode is Ctrl+Shift+T.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no way to save a fiddle (or a forked fiddle) in JSFiddle as anonymous without logging out.  That is an interesting idea, and would make a good [feature request](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues), however.